# Why kendo Grid is not generating any html output and no serverside/clientside errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this kendo grid in one of my views:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<IJRayka.Core.Utility.ViewModels.OrderDto>
@using IJRayka.Core.Web.Code
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Order List";
}

<h2>Order List</h2>
    @{
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(ord => ord.CustomerName);
        columns.Bound(ord => ord.MarketerName);
        columns.Bound(ord => ord.OrderDate);
        columns.Template(ord => ord.CurrentStatus.GetDisplayName());
        columns.Bound(ord => ord.PaymentMethod);
        columns.Bound(ord => ord.Description);
        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit().Text("ویرایش"));
        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Select().Text("مشاهده"));
        columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Destroy().Text("حذف"));

    }).DataSource(ds => ds.Server()
        .Model(m => m.Id(ord => ord.ID))
            .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "OrderManagement"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Details", "OrderManagement"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "OrderManagement"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "OrderManagement"))
        ).Pageable().Sortable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("ایجاد سفارش"))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)));
}
```

When I debug, I see there is 4 items in the Model collection, but I don't know why without any errors, the grid won't show up at all. Not a single HTML tag is generated on client side, and there's no errors shown in the firebug console.

It was working great before, but all of a sudden, after some changes to my model I don't know what happened to it.

**EDIT**:
I just realized if I write this all lines, in **one single line** it works !
But I don't understand why?

Comment: I don't see the `@` before the `Html.Kendo()`... Please post your exact view code (expecillay the full Grid part)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the construct `@{ .. }` then you are in a code block in razor. And inside in a code block nothing gets written to the response by default.

You need to use `@` to output something to the output or you need to use some special methods like `Render()` on the Grid.

So the following invocations are all working:

Using `Render` on [any Kendo Widget:](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/WidgetBuilderBase#methods-Render)

```
@{
    Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
    {
      //...
    })
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)))
    .Render(); //Render method provided by Kendo UI.
}
```

Using `@`:

```
@{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
    {
      //...
    })
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))))
}
```

Or if you anyway have this one statement in the code block don't use the code block at all just write:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
{
    //...
})
.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))))
```

Note: if youe have a multiline statement after the `@` you need to wrap the whole statement with an extra set of parens (`()`)

Comment: thank you, +1 for good explanation. Another problem is if I put @ in the beginning of `Html.Kendo()` in my code above, `.ToolBar` turns to red as an error. It just won't understand a multiline code block.

Comment: @Ashkan yeah you are right. `@` is not enough if you have a multiline statement you need to use `@(...)` so you need to wrap the whole thing in parens. I've updated my answer.